# Compiler says: the trait bound `Foo: serde::de::Deserialize` is not satisfied - when it is

Tags: rust

I endeavour to save my struct to user preferences. My code follows

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use preferences::AppInfo;

const APP_INFO: AppInfo = AppInfo{name: "some-name", author: "some-author"};
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub struct Foo {
    bar: i32
}

fn main() {
    let x = Foo{bar: 12};

    // Attempt 1: cannot find a `save` function
    // x.save(x, &APP_INFO, "foo/bar").unwrap();

    // Attempt 2: Foo leaves Serialize & Deserialise unsatisfied
    preferences::Preferences::save(&x, &APP_INFO, "foo/bar").unwrap();

}
```

Despite this line `#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]` the compiler grumbles ..

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Foo: serde::ser::Serialize` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:17:5
    |
17  |     preferences::Preferences::save(&x, &APP_INFO, "foo/bar").unwrap();
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `serde::ser::Serialize` is not implemented for `Foo`
    | 
   ::: /Users/martincowie/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/preferences-1.1.0/src/lib.rs:302:16
    |
302 |     fn save<S: AsRef<str>>(&self, app: &AppInfo, key: S) -> Result<(), PreferencesError>;
    |                ---------- required by this bound in `save`
    |
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Preferences` for `Foo`
```

The unsatisfied trait bound `<S: AsRef<str>>` relates to the parameter `key`, which is a string literal.

This is more or less inspired by the example at https://docs.rs/preferences/1.1.0/preferences/

What need I do to placate the compiler?

Comment: Wow, that error message! Not only that it claims that `Foo` doesn't implement `Serialize` and `Deserialize` without explanation about the version conflict. It also claims that some trait bound for a completely different parameter and completely different trait somehow leads to the requirement that `Foo` needs to implement `Serialize` and `Deserialize`. That's pretty random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your cargo.lock. Most likely, your main application is pulling in a different version of `serde` than the `preferences` crate.

It appears that `preferences` depends on `serde-0.9`, but chances are you're pulling in `serde-1.0`. This means that your struct implements `serde-1.0::Deserialize`, but `preferences` wants `serde-0.9::Deserialize`.

The inability of the compiler to produce a nice message for this case is a long-standing bug.

Comment: Thanks Seb, that resolves this issue, but causes another. I also depend on `csv v1.1.6`, which depends on `serde 1.0.125`, so changing my dependency to an earlier version of `serde` upsets `csv`. Is there an elegant solution to this?

Comment: `serde` is one of the crates you should only ever have a single instance of in your dependency graph, and that single instance should be version 1.x, since that's what virtually all crates use. The `preferences` crate appears to be abandoned – tha last version was published more than four years ago. Your best bet is to either use a different crate for your use case (which most likely exists), or port the old `preferences` crate to serde 1.0 yourself (which most likely isn't much work).

Comment: Thanks Sven. My working solution is to get `preferences` from https://github.com/baysmith/preferences-rs.git instead of `crates.io`, which feels _wrong_ but does work. I agree that `preferences` feels abandoned - is there a process to mark it so on `crates.io` or a process for a new maintainer to refresh it?